# Can't upload PFX in new Azure portal

Tags: azure, certificate, pfx, azureportal

I cannot upload the PFX file http://screencast.com/t/CM8bCZvUxmg while still can do that in the old portal https://manage.windowsazure.com/. Does any one know why? I hope it is not an Azure bugs!

Comment: It may just be a Glitch on the page, clear the cookies and open the page again, should work well for you.

Comment: No, it's a permanent issue :(

Comment: hmm strange, can you use a shorter name for your pfx file

Comment: already did that but no luck still!

Comment: Same problem here.  pfx with private key does not upload.  Works in old portal